# symfony2 "Erroneous data format for unserializing user entity" (FOS UserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, authentication

I develop in symfony2 but am no sym2 wiz, brought in help to set everything up with the framework, and now it's throwing me a sudden error message I can't resolve.

I have two development environments, and one that I hadn't been using for a couple of months suddenly hit me with this error message upon trying to log in to my sym2 webapp locally:

"Erroneous data format for unserializing [user entity]"

I have not changed the code for logging in, I have not updated my vendors, and I have not changed any settings in MAMP (could it have updated itself though and done that?)

I don't understand what is going on.

I can google the error and I am suggested to hack one of the vendor source files. I would not know exactly what I would have done, so I am not comfortable with doing that just following some step-by-step instruction.

The application is running on symfony 2.3.9 and MAMP is set to PHP 5.6.27, the other option is 7.0.12 which produces the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I changed my doctrine version to

```
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
```

and it resolved the issue. Now I don't know what other issues THAT might have introduced seeing sym2 isn't always too backwards compatible, but fingers crossed =)